# How do I have a user enter words line by line until the Enter key is pressed?

Tags: python

I had a homework assignment that required me to check each word in a list for a specific letter, and tell the user how many of the words in the list contained the letter. Below is my code for this:

```
letterSearch = input("Please enter a letter to search for: ")

w = ['', '', '', '']
w[0] = input("Please enter up to 4 words: ")
w[1] = input(": ")
w[2] = input(": ")
w[3] = input(": ")

first = 0
second = 0
third = 0
fourth = 0

for ch in w[0]:
    if ch is letterSearch:
        first = 1
for ch in w[1]:
    if ch is letterSearch:
        second = 1
for ch in w[2]:
    if ch is letterSearch:
        third = 1
for ch in w[3]:
    if ch is letterSearch:
        fourth = 1

ans = first + second + third + fourth

print(ans, "of the entered words contain the letter", letterSearch)
```

The problem I was having was that in the homework, the professor wanted the user to be able to input words until the enter key was pressed, whereas I set the maximum amount of words that could be entered to 4. Is there a way to have the user be able to input any number of words, with the words still being separated in the list, until the enter key is pressed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To split a string with any number of words (given that they are delimited by a space ), use the built-in `.split()` function like so:

```
my_str = "this sentence has some words"
print(my_str.split())

>>> ['this', 'sentence', 'has', 'some', 'words']
```

Aside from this, your code also has some factoring issues. It's impractical for you to manually search each word for the letter, given that you will not know the number of words. It would be better for you to iterate through the list of spliced words:

```
letter_search = input("Please enter a letter to search for: ")

words = input("Please enter some words: ")
words = words.split()

in_word_count = 0

# Go through the list of words;
for word in words:
    # Check if the letter specified is in the word
    if letter_search in word:
        # Increment the count
        in_word_count += 1

print(in_word_count, "of the entered words contain the letter", letter_search)
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the whole of the input as a single string, then use `split` to break it up into a list of words.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split` on a string to divide it up into pieces. Just ask your user to separate the words provided to `input` with some character: spaces are a convenient one. Then you can create a list from the inputted string and proceed as with the rest of your assignment.

```
>>> w = input("Please enter words separated by spaces:")
Please enter words separated by spaces:one two three four five six
>>> w
'one two three four five six'
>>> w_list = w.split(" ")
>>> w_list
['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six']
```